# Strange ''sign in attempt prevented'' messages on Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, privacy, google-account, security

These messages from no-reply@accounts.google.com say something like this:

> Hi (my name),
> Someone just tried to sign in to your account (my Gmail)from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.
>
> Details:
> (time and date)
> (location)
>
> We strongly reccomend to use a secure app like Gmail, to access your account. All apps made by Google meet these security standards. Using a less secure app, on the other hand, could leave your account vulnerable. (learn more link)

I don’t know if this is legit or not, but it appears in my Gmail 1-3 times a day, which is pretty strange.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Are you using any app for Gmail? Also, is "reccomend" your own typo or was it like that in the message?

Comment: "say something like" - You need to be more precise. If you paste the _exact_  wording of the email then it will be much easier to determine whether it is legit or not. There could be many "fake" emails that "say something like this". Spelling mistakes (as Live Forever mentions) are often a telltale sign of phishing attempts.

Answer (score 1):

It usually happens when you try to sign in your account using another device or at any other place other than frequently used devices.

If it happens thrice a day, then either your account is being signed in by any other person of your circle or someone is trying to hack your account from other places.

Because Google recognises devices quickly and sends you an email to ensure security of account.

It’s just a suggestion.

Comment: Whilst this could well be the case, the _official_ "New sign-in from..." email that Google sends is quite different to the "something like" text posted in the question. For instance, the _official_ email makes no mention of using a "secure app" (etc.) as stated in the last paragraph and there isn't a "learn more link" in the location stated. That could suggest a prime phishing attack (particularly with the frequency of these messages).

Comment: Actually, there are two different emails for this. One for sign-ins from a new, non-frequently used, device, and another when trying to sign-in to gmail via a client it perceives as unsecure (such as Thunderbird on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Typically you shouldn't be receiving these emails three times a day. When you do receive them (legitimately), you'll see a red notification bar in Google areas when signed in with your account.

For safety's sake, I would either enable [Google 2-Step Verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) on your account, or at least change the password. When in doubt, if you're a paid Google Apps member, you can contact Google support.

Last idea, I've had this issue when I used a VPN. I'm not sure if you're using any IP changing or hiding software, but that could definitely be the culprit.